# accessing php variable inside ESI tag

Tags: php, varnish, esi

currently trying to use the ESI include feature of varnish caching system with a php project. in my scenario I need to access the php variables inside the esi tag. something like following...

```
 <p class="dt5">This article was read <esi:include src="http://localhost/live24/esi/viewCount" /> times. </p>
```

here is the full url inside the esi tag and it works fine i.e. fetch the read count from the server and the rest of the page is served from cache. but how can I generate a dynamic url which I can pass to the esi tag.

I have tried something like following ....

```
<?php $url = site_url() . "/esi/viewCount" ?>
```

or

```
<?php $url = "http://localhost/live24/esi/viewCount" ?>
<p class="dt5">This article was read <esi:include src="$(url)" /> times. </p>
```

as the `$(variable_name)` or `$(variable_name{key_name})` is the syntax for adding variable inside the esi tag but seems like it's not working while accessing a PHP variable.

I have tried something like this also ...

```
<p class="dt5">This article was read<esi:include src="http://$(SERVER{NAME})/live24/esi/viewCount" /> times. </p>
```

and this works. indicating that I can access the superglobals from inside the esi tag.

is there any way to access the php variables inside the esi tag or any other way to generate a dynamic url to use in the esi include.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution and it's pretty simple and straightforward actually. should have thought about that earlier.

first the code snippet..

```
<p class="dt5">This article was read
  <esi:remove>
    <?php $esiUrl = "http://localhost/bdlive24/esi/viewCount"; ?>
  </esi:remove>

  <!--esi
    <esi:include src=<?php echo $esiUrl; ?> />
  -->
times</p>
```

here the trick is introducing the `<esi:remove>` tag. any markup code inside the remove tag will just be ignored and php code will be executed. So now any dynamic url generation inside the esi:remove tag and binding it inside the esi:include tag is possible.

`<!-- ... -->` this tag will just be removed by varnish silently when ESI processing is enabled and in case of ESI processing disabled this tag will come into action and make the esi:include tag inactive.

Anyone having any other idea, please share ....